# slicing strings with variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

I am making a python program where I need to inspect individual four letter parts of a variable. If the variable is for example **help_me_code_please** it should output **ease** then **e_pl** etc , I attempted it with

```
a=0
b=3
repetitions=5
word="10011100110000111010"
for x in range (1,repetitions):        
    print(word[a:b])
    a=a+4
    b=b+4
```

however it just outputs empty lines. 
Thanks so much for any help in advanced.

Comment: Hey @Uriel, what is `repitions` and `word` in the code above? These don't appear to have been defined which would explain your problem

Comment: This answer has worked for me in the past: https://stackoverflow.com/a/312464/3282436

Comment: Please show the “word” and “repititions” variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
words = "help_me_code_please"
size = 4
start = len(words)%size - size

for i in reversed(range(start, len(words), size)):
    print(words[max(0,i):i+size])
```

output is

```
ease
e_pl
_cod
p_me
hel
```

Explanation: `start` gives us a starting point, that is some divisible block away from the length of our string (words). In our example, it's `-1`, as that is `20 (5*4)` away from `19`, the length of `words`.

Now we do a reverse loop, from `19 -> -1` at size four. So we go 15, 11, 7, 3, -1. Within each loop, we print from our position to the position + 4. So the first loop iteration prints out `words[15:19]` which outputs `ease`, the second is `words[11:15]`, etc etc. This results in the output we see.

Hopefully this explanation makes sense!

Comment: Thank you so much, would it be possible to be

Comment: I think you didn't finish your sentence @UrielSasieni!

Comment: Thank you so much, would it be possible to be outputed as: ease , e_pl , _cod , p_me , _hel

Comment: hey @UrielSasieni, updated my answer. Now outputs as you want it.

Comment: thats perfect, would you mind explaining it to me , thank you so much for your help

Comment: Added an explanation, hopefully that helps

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want print the word backwards with a repetition of 4.

```
word = 'help_me_code_please'

# Looping from backwards on the word with a step of 4
for i in range(len(word)-1, -1, -4):
    # j is the starting point from where we have to print the string.
    j = i-3 if i > 3 else i-1
    print word[j:i+1]
```

Answer (score 0):

For forward:

```
[word[4*l:4*(l+1)] for l in range(0, int(len(word)/4)+1)]
['help', '_me_', 'code', '_ple', 'ase']
```

For backward:

```
[word[::-1][4*l:4*(l+1)][::-1] for l in range(0, int(len(word)/4)+1)]
['ease', 'e_pl', '_cod', 'p_me', 'hel']
```

This is list comprehensions (https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), you can iterate the resulting list.

Its var[start:ends:step]. word[::-1] means get a letter, start at the beginning, finish at the end, and advance -1 steps, so it reverse the string

For the new values:

```
word="10011100110000111010"
[word[4*l:4*(l+1)] for l in range(0, int(len(word)/4)+1)]
['1001', '1100', '1100', '0011', '1010']

[word[::-1][4*l:4*(l+1)] for l in range(0, int(len(word)/4)+1)]
['0101', '1100', '0011', '0011', '1001']
```

Comment: it says s is not defined

Comment: Sorry, i used a var s and didn't change to word. Corrected